Firebase SMS Authentication Fails for Most Networks in Tanzania with Error Code -39
I've noticed that Firebase SMS authentication consistently fails for the majority of mobile networks in Tanzania, consistently returning the error code
 auth/error-code: -39

Initially, this issue seemed isolated to Airtel Tanzania, but it has progressively impacted other networks over the past six months. Firebase support attributed the problem with Airtel to delivery issues, but the problem has since expanded to affect all networks except Vodacom Tanzania.
Specifically, with Tigo network, only numbers starting with +25577 seem to work, while others fail. I've tested different phone number prefixes across various networks, and the results are as follows:
+25561??????? Vietell ❌
+25562??????? Vietell ❌
+25565??????? Tigo  ❌
+25566??????? Benson ❌
+25568??????? Airtel ❌
+25569??????? Airtel ❌
+255711?????? tigo ❌
+255732?????? TTCL ✅
+255741?????? Vodacom ✅
+255751?????? Vodacom ✅
+255761?????? Vodacom ✅
+25577??????? Tigo ✅
+25578??????? Airtel ❌


Despite Firebase support's explanation, the issue persists and impacts a significant portion of valid phone number is Tanzania. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
